# Question on a recurring sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $[n]$ denote the set of first $n$ natural numbers along with $0.$ For each $n \in \mathbb N$ define a map $p^{(n)} : [n] \times [n] \longrightarrow [0,1]$ as follows $:$

$p^{(n)} (i,j) = p^{(n)} (j,i)$ for all $0 \leq i,j \leq n,$ $p^{(n)} (i,0) = p^{(n)} (0,i) = \frac {1} {2}$ for $i \neq 0,$ $p^{(n)} (i,i) = \frac {1} {2}$ for $i \neq 0,$ $p^{(n)} (0,0) = 1$ and for $i \neq j$ with $i,j \neq 0$ let $$p^{(n)} (i,j) = \frac {\sum\limits_{0 \leq k \leq i - 1, \ 0 \leq l \leq j-1} p^{(n-1)} (k,l)} {(i+2)(j+2)}.$$ Let $p^{(n)} = \sum\limits_{0 \leq i,j \leq n} p^{(n)} (i,j).$ Then what can we say about the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n^2} \left (p^{(n)} - \frac {n^2} {4} \right )\ $?

Actually this problem is motivated from a problem of random graphs in probability theory. I have computed few terms of the sequence $p^{(n)}$ but don't find any pattern to determine general terms.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without a word on your motivations and efforts. This kind of post is usually closed...\

Comment: @PierreCarre$:$ Is it possible to determine the convergence of the series by writing a program?

Comment: The computations suggest that the general term drops below $0$ and stays negative bounded away from $0$, so the series diverges to $-\infty$. Will you be happy with such result?

Comment: @fedja$:$ Could you please elaborate a little more as to why is it happening? Could you please share your computation for determining the general term? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At this moment I just ran some computer experiments but I can try to turn it into a formal proof if that helps. The ultimate reason is clear, however: the division by $(i+2)(j+2)$ instead of natural $ij$ (the size of the rectangle) is too strong and brings the average down at every step. The three extra $1/2$ you throw into each layer are just too weak to bring it back up. Are you sure that $+2$ is, indeed, correct?

Comment: Actually, the formal reason is quite trivial: one can show by straightforward induction that all non-trivial entries are below $\frac 3{14}<\frac 14$.

Comment: How do you show that @fedja?

Comment: Erm... Check the base ($n=0$, where the statement is vacuous) , assume that it holds for $i,j<n$ and show it for $i,j\le n$ using the induction assumption. Note that your $p^{(n)}$ actually all agree as soon as they are defined, so the superscript ${}^{(n)}$ is not really needed. Let me know if you have some difficulty with the induction step, of course, but I believe you should be able to manage it yourself :-)